# Alexa skill using Node.js on Azure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am going to develop my first Alexa skill and have the back-end portion reside on Azure.  I can find plenty of Node.js on AWS or C# on Azure for back-end functions.  However, I can't find any examples of Node.js / Azure to help me get going.  (I am fighting the temptation of picking the easy path route by using C#)

Can you suggest a link I can reference for developing an Alexa skill in Node.js on Azure or is C# the better suited for the back-end functions?  Thank you

Comment: I think this could help you https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  How does one use the sdk or are there examples of how to use it?

Comment: Scroll down until you reach "Samples" ...